# React app axios fetched data is displayed in localhost but won't be displayed in mobile

Tags: reactjs, mobile, axios, localhost

So I am currently working on a React page to display some data from a third-party API, and the page loads successfully on my PC but for some reason it doesn't display the fetched data in mobile. I'm doing trials using localhost to work on the page but I would like to try using my phone in order to verify that it's running correctly and encountered this problem.

This is what I have in my Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// Es donde se hace "wire-in" o se "instalan" los paquetes o controladores a utilizar.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var provider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
var configuration = provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    var frontendURL = configuration.GetValue<string>("frontend_url");
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
        //builder.WithOrigins(frontendURL).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
// Esto sería el middleware.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

This is what I have coded in Visual Studio in my controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MoviesRouletteReactApp.Models;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
//using System.Text.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Unicode;
using RestSharp;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using System.IO.Pipes;

namespace MoviesRouletteReactApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [EnableCors]
        [Route("GetNowPlayingMoviesBackdrops")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetNowPlayingMoviesBackdrops()
        {

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var movieIds = new List<int>();
                var nowPlayingMoviesBackdrops = new List<string>();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?language=en-US&page=1");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Auth.bearer_token);
                var response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
                // El GetAsync retorna un mensaje, no el mero dato, por eso se estableció la condicional con
                // response.IsSuccessStatusCode para verificar que saliera success.
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {


                    var stringResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    var nowPlayingMovies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movies>(stringResponse);
                    // Retorna TODO el listado de datos del JSON.
                    // Este for es para poder guardar en una lista movieIds
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        // Para hacer uso de solamente los resultados, hay que acceder al campo de "results" que es uno de
                        // los campos dentro del JSON.
                        movieIds.Add(nowPlayingMovies.results[i].id);
                    }
                    using (var client2 = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < movieIds.Count; i++)
                        {
                            client2.BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{movieIds[i]}/images?language=en");
                            client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Auth.bearer_token);
                            var response2 = await client.GetAsync(client2.BaseAddress);
                            if (response2.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            {
                                var stringResponse2 = response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                                var nowPlayingMoviesImages = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MovieImages>(stringResponse2);

                                for (int j = 0; j < nowPlayingMoviesImages.backdrops.Length; j++)
                                {
                                    if (nowPlayingMoviesImages.backdrops[j].height == 2160 && nowPlayingMoviesImages.backdrops[j].iso_639_1 == "en")
                                    {
                                        nowPlayingMoviesBackdrops.Add(nowPlayingMoviesImages.backdrops[j].file_path);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                        //return RedirectToAction("GetMoviesBackdrops");
                        //return Ok(nowPlayingMoviesIds);
                    
                    return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nowPlayingMoviesBackdrops, Formatting.Indented));
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new HttpRequestException(response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And lastly, this is what I have in my React component:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { urlNowPlayingMoviesBackdrops } from '../endpoints';
import './NowPlaying.css'

function NowPlaying() {
    const [nowPlayingFirst10, setNowPlayingFirst10] = useState<any>([]);
    //const [result, setResult] = useState<any>([]);
    const handleNowPlayingFirst10 = (newItem: Array<string>) => {
        setNowPlayingFirst10((nowPlayingFirst10: Array<string>) => [...nowPlayingFirst10, newItem]);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(urlNowPlayingMoviesBackdrops)
        .then((response: AxiosResponse<any>) => {
            //console.log(result);
            var tempArray: Array<string> = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                if (response.data.indexOf(response.data[i], 0) == 0) {
                    const markup: any = [
                        {carousel_class: "carousel-item active", data_bs_interval: "3000",
                        img_class: "d-block w-100", img_alt: "...", img_src: `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${response.data[i]}`,
                        carousel_cap_class: "carousel-caption movie-desc", h5_class: "label", desc_class: "desc-paragraph"
                        }];
                    tempArray = tempArray.concat(markup);
                }
                else {
                    const markup: any = [
                        {carousel_class: 'carousel-item', data_bs_interval: "3000",
                        img_class: "d-block w-100", img_alt: "...", img_src: `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${response.data[i]}`,
                        carousel_cap_class: "carousel-caption movie-desc", h5_class: "label", desc_class: "desc-paragraph"
                        }];
                    tempArray = tempArray.concat(markup);
                }
            }
            setNowPlayingFirst10(tempArray);
        })
        .catch (error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }, [])
            
    return (
        <>
        {
            React.Children.toArray(nowPlayingFirst10.map((item: any, i: number) => {
                return(
                    <>
                    <div key={i} className={item.carousel_class} data-bs-interval={item.data_bs_interval}>
                        <img key={i} src={item.img_src} className={item.img_class} alt={item.img_alt} />
                    </div>
                    </>
                )
            }))
        }
        </> 
    );
}

export default NowPlaying;
```

Some of the things I tried were:

1. Changed from the Axios module to the fetch library to verify if axios would somehow be messing with my code but it doesn't seem to make a difference.
2. Based on what I read on some forums and other questions posted here in Stack Overflow, I tried changing from localhost to the actual IP in the environment variables but it still doesn't seem to display the fetched data from axios on the mobile device.
3. I tried using the VS extension Conveyor which supposedly opens the web api for access to any device on the network and still the data is not displayed in the mobile device.
4. Opened up the ports in the windows firewall, adding all the ports in use, including the front-end, the backend and even the port assigned by Conveyor.